# jquery: modify multiple hrefs

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery("a.leftM").attr("href", "?g");
```

I have a few links on a page, to which I would like to **add** the parameter ?g. The sample above only replaces it. After some research I tried the following (which does not seem to work at all);

```
$("a.leftM").each(function(){
    var x = this.attr("href");
    this.attr("href", x+"?g");
});
```

What am I missing here?
Is there a prettier/shorter way than to use a function?

Cheers H

Comment: That's not a very efficient way of doing it. My fingers were moving faster than my brain at first, but my corrected answer is how it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `$(this).attr()` instead of `this.attr()`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.leftM").attr("href", function(){
        return $(this).attr("href") + "?g";  
    });
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bYqKD/1/

Comment: Outside of a function block, `this` is just going to refer to the `window` object.

Comment: Sorry, it's true - but I'm happy to rescind the downvote when the answer's fixed.